# What is best a wireless router with 8 ports or a dedicated 8 port router/switch for home use?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, smart-home

I am in the process of buying a new home and every room (Study, Living Room, Game room and all 4 bed rooms) have hard lined ethernet ports. The gang of wires are located in the Master bedroom closet currently without any form of network switch. That leaves me with a need to get them all connected and also connect wireless for optimum use.

The ISP will be AT&T (no choice). So whatever I do it will need to work with their system (I have read of some system incompatibilities).

My current thinking is to hook up a WIFI router with 8 ports and let it handle it that way, however that will mean the WIFI router will be in the master bedroom closet, furthest from the main part of the house (and mounted or placed close to an exterior wall).

Another possibility, which I do not know if this exists, since every room has a internet drop, is to hook up a router/switch in the panel and get "weak" WIFI for each bedroom since their need will most likely never involve a direct connection.

I would also like to keep everything on the same subnet to make it easier to connect to wireless AIO printer and other home devices from any device. I am looking for the simplest/best (in that order) setup for this situation.

Any recommendations outside of what I am thinking are welcome too.